# hypergeometric 2F2 function close form for specific case

Tags: functions, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to find the closed form for the following

\begin{equation}
{_2F_2}(2,4;3,4+a;a)
\end{equation}

any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

I find the closed form for
\begin{equation}
{_2F_2}(1,3;2,3+a;a)=1+\frac{a}{2}
\end{equation}
But don't success to solve the first sum

Answer (score 1):

$_2F_2(2,4;3,4+a;a)$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2)_n(4)_na^n}{(3)_n(a+4)_nn!}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(n+3)(2)_na^n}{3(a+4)_nn!}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(n+2)(2)_na^n}{3(a+4)_nn!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2)_na^n}{3(a+4)_nn!}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2)_{n+1}a^n}{3(a+4)_nn!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2)_na^n}{3(a+4)_nn!}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2(3)_{n}a^n}{3(a+4)_nn!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2)_na^n}{3(a+4)_nn!}$

$=\dfrac{2}{3}{}_1F_1(3;a+4;a)+\dfrac{1}{3}{}_1F_1(2;a+4;a)$

$=\dfrac{(a+3)(a+2)(a+1)}{3}\int_0^1x^2(1-x)^ae^{ax}~dx+\dfrac{(a+3)(a+2)}{3}\int_0^1x(1-x)^{a+1}e^{ax}~dx$

Which is expected to related to incomplete gamma function

Comment: \begin{equation}
{_2F_2}(1,3;2,\frac{(3\gamma+\lambda)}{ \gamma};\frac{ \lambda}{ \gamma})=1+\frac{ \lambda}{2 \gamma}
\end{equation}
Easy to verify: for lambda=1 gamma=1 we get 1+1/2=1.5, for lambda=8 gamma=2 we get 1+8/4=3
I get this result from stochastic process analysis. So I wonder does we can get similar simple result for the formula from my answer